# IBM MobileFirst Sql Adapter Prod build not working in IOS

Tags: ios, sql, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter

We are worked IBM MobileFirst mobile app.We have one SQL Adapter getting userinfo from DB.We are working on PROD build. Below code working fine with Android.But it's not working for IOS

CODE:

```
function fetchUserInfo(params) {
    var data = JSON.parse(params)
    data.status = "ACTIVE";
    var response = WL.Server.invokeProcedure({
        adapter: "SQLAdapter",
        procedure: "fetchUserInfos",
        parameters: [data],
    });
    return response;
}
var querySavedCards  = "SELECT distinct(TOKEN),USERNAME,USERSTARTDATE,USERSTARTDATE from MFPAPP.USERINF ";
function fetchUserInfos(params){
    return MFP.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : querySavedCards,
        parameters : [params.status, params.loginID]
    });
}
```

Please guide to us .For IOS we need do any thing extra.

Comment: This is server side code. It does not matter Android or iOS here. 
What happens when iOS device makes the adapter call? And what version of MFP is this?

Comment: @VivinK thanks for reply .MFP version 8.0.0 .We got Error Response "Internal Server error 500" .But this issue we are getting only ios not in android

Comment: var response = WL.Server.invokeProcedure({
        adapter: "SQLAdapter",
        procedure: "fetchUserInfos",
        parameters: [data],
    });

It should be MFP.Server.invokeProcedure.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/MFP.Server.html#MFP.Server.invokeProcedure
Share the stacktrace in the logs.